# titlesec adds extra space on top of chapter number in report class

Tags: spacing, titlesec

This is the third question in a series of questions I've asked regarding titlesec adding extra space on top of the chapter number. I am using the report class and I want the space above chapter number to be exactly one inch (edit: one inch from top of page not margin!). In my other post someone directed me to an old post that has a solution for the report class but for two inch spacing. I've posted that solution here. Can someone please tell me how I can change this code so it makes the spacing to one inch? In addition, how can I fix the same issue for the title of the table of contents?  I need the title of ToC to be exactly one inch from top of page as well. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\topskip+\baselineskip-\ht\strutbox-1in\relax}

\titleformat{\chapter}
    [display]
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}
    {\large\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
    {.1in}
    {}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}
    {0pt} % left
    {-\mylen} % before
    {.5in} % after

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\chapter{Hello}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: seems like it already set to 1in.

Comment: wait, you wanna 1in from top of the page, not top of margin right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. 1 inch from top of page.

Comment: you can delete the `-1in` from `\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\topskip+\baselineskip-\ht\strutbox-1in\relax}`